# Surrounding text with tag and populating tag

Tags: html, text

I have several lines of text, in them there is a word or words that are capitalized like this:

Hello HOW ARE YOU good to see you
I am FINE

Is there a tool that can go through the text and surround all those capitalized with the HTML anchor text?

and

I guess more difficultly, also populate the href with uncapitalized, space(s) removed version of that capitalized text?

Any help on one or both questions is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want this to happen client-side, or server-side? Is the input plain text, or X(HT)ML?

Comment: Client side preferably, input text is plain

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while, but here it is in javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/RdJ4E/4/

I'm sure you will find the way hot to tune the code. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Is this a beginning? Matching all uppercased words is trivial with regex, and with providing the String.replace method with a callback function instead of a string you can do whatever you want with the matched string.

```
myString.replace(/(\b[A-Z\s]+\b)/g, function(result, match){
    var stripped = encodeURI(result.trim().toLowerCase());
    return ' <a href="http://www.google.com/search?q='+stripped+'">'+result.trim()+'</a> ';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mwxnC/2/